# React Ant design 4 Input search display table data

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

I'm tried to create Ant design 4 input search to filter data , Name and age, when i search name or age wanna display table data but its not working anyone know how to do that correctly

***[stazkblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ghvwxl?file=index.js)***

**code here**

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name",
    render: text => <a>{text}</a>
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age"
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32
  }
];
const onSearch = value => console.log(value);
ReactDOM.render(
<div><Search
      placeholder="input search text"
      allowClear
      enterButton="Search"
      size="large"
      onSearch={onSearch}
    />
    <br/>
       <br/>   <br/>
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} /></div>,
    document.getElementById('container')
 
);
```

Thanks

Comment: do you expect that on Search your table to display only filtered data based on your input? like, user types '32', table should show 'John Brown' and 'Joe Black'? if he search for 'J' should show all 3, or only for exact match?

Comment: @buzatto yes, did you know how to do that? type 32 in the input and display table data

Comment: yes, I will take a look into your code to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you need to extract your code to create a component;
- create a `filterInput` state with `React.useState`, that holds inputSearch value. `React.useState` returns an array, where the first value is state, and second is a function to update that state value;
- create a function `filterData` based on `filterInput` to filter your data table;

for `filterData` I return all data if it's empty. I check if is not a number to decide how to filter, by name or age.

```
function App() {
  const [filterInput, setFilterInput] = React.useState('')
  const filterData = () => {
    if(filterInput === '') return data

    if(isNaN(filterInput)) {
      return data.filter(({ name }) => name.includes(filterInput))
    }
    return data.filter(({ age }) => age === +filterInput)
  }

  return <div><Search
      placeholder="input search text"
      allowClear
      enterButton="Search"
      size="large"
      onSearch={setFilterInput}
    />
    <br/>
       <br/>   <br/>
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={filterData()} /></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
,
    document.getElementById('container')
 
);
```

[sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/search-data?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Table, Input } from 'antd';
import surveyList from './surveyList';

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name",
    render: text => <a>{text}</a>
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age"
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32
  }
]; 


function SearchTable() {
  const [filterTable, setFilterTable] = useState(null);

  const onSearch = (value) => {
    // const filterData = data.filter((item) => item.survey.includes(value));
    const filterData = data.filter((o) => Object.keys(o).some((k) => String(o[k])
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(value.toLowerCase())));
    setFilterTable(filterData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Input.Search
        style={{ border: '3px solid red', margin: '0 0 10px 0' }}
        placeholder="Search by..."
        enterButton
        onSearch={onSearch}
      />
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={filterTable == null ? data : filterTable}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchTable;
```